# ASP.NET Web Api 2 routing issue

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I really can't understand why it does not work. I have the following code:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}

[RoutePrefix("api/Profile")]
[System.Web.Http.AuthorizeAttribute]
[IdentityBasicAuthenticationAttribute]
public class ProfileApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateApiContentLength]
    [ValidateApiMimeMultipart]
    [Route("Upload")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadDocumentAsync(string description)
    {
       //....
    }
}
```

}

but when I call: http://localhost:11015/api/profile/Upload

I get 404 error:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:11015/api/profile/Upload'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'ProfileApi' that matches the request."
}
```

but insight says about error:

[image]

what is incorrect?

Comment: 1. How did you make the call? 2. Which template are you using for the project: asp mvc or asp mvc web api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. Problem was not in the routing. Problem was in parameter of action. It should not be there for POST method. Other things leave as is

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateApiContentLength]
    [ValidateApiMimeMultipart]
    [Route("upload")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadDocumentAsync()
    {
```

Answer (score 0):

WebApi routing can't find your **UploadDocumentAsync** method. In your application you're using both the routing table (in the WebApiConfig class) and attribute routing. You don't need the latter.

You can leave the routing table in the WebApiConfig class as is and drop the **Route** and **RoutePrefix** attributes.

Change your action UploadDocumentAsync in the Profile controller  to:

```
...
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> UploadUploadDocumentAsync(string description)
{
...
```

just leaving the **HttpPost** attribute.

You can reach your your resource by calling (you can do it via Fiddler, for exampe):

POST http://localhost:11015/api/profile/

UPDATE:

Or if you would really like to have the "upload" part in your url, you *can* utilize the Route attribute for the action:

```
[Route("api/profile/upload")]
```

Comment: First: The OP wants to use attribute routing and is asking about why the attribute routing is not working. Therefore, you suggesting not to use attribute routing does not answer the question, Second: `[Route("api/profile/upload")]` is also changing the way the OP has designed the routing, Therefore, both suggestions are suggesting to change the design and thus do not answer the question.

Comment: First: OP didn't ask exactly *attribute* routing, perhaps table routing will suffice. Second: api/profile/upload will allow him to use a url like: http(s)://{host}/api/profile/upload what OP wants.

Comment: @CodingYoshi, having re-read the question in the morning, I guess there's a possibility that you might be right. OlegSh, if this is the case, please let us.

Comment: @serge.karalenka ,[Route("api/profile/upload")] does not work at all... Seems, routing is correct, because App Insight say about exception. But why it does not work?